# Не работает команда бан

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Не могу понять что не так в этом коде:

```py
#Команда для бана
@bot.command( pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True)
async def ban( ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = 0xEC2C2D,
    title="Ban",
    description=f"Ban user { member.mention }",
    )
    embed.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    embed.set_author( name = bot.user.name, icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url ))
```

Выдает эту ошибку:

```py
  File "<string>", line 139
    embed.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Т.е. ничего необычного в том, что строчка начинается с закрывающей скобки, вы не видите? 

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что футер нужно сунуть в ембед к дескриптниону?))

Comment: Нет. Но у вас очень странный вывод.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xEC2C2D, title="Ban", description=f"Ban user { member.mention }")
    embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_author(name=bot.user.name, icon_url=bot.user.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!